# Importing CSV file in Neo4j

Tags: database, csv, import, neo4j, cypher

While using this command

`LOAD CSV FROM "file:///artists.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line.Name, year: toInt(line.Year)})`

I am getting
**Error**: `Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node or Relationship but was List<String> (line 2, column 25 (offset: 68))
"CREATE (:Artist { name: line.Name, year: toInt(line.Year)})"`

**CSV file**

`"1","ABBA","1992"
"2","Roxette","1986"
"3","Europe","1979"
"4","The Cardigans","1992"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV has no header, so you can't access a column by its name, ie when you do this : `line.Name`.

You have to do it by the column index : `line[0]`

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Please try

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///artists.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line.Name, year: toInt(line.Year)})

Make sure you have Name and Year columns in the atists.csv file